# gson - passing fromJson with a nested json string to an Object

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am learning Java and Android development. I learned the beginning part pretty quick so far. But I am stuck with using the json data coming from a JsonObjectRequest from URL.

I created a class to welcome the array, but I don't know how I will get the key value pairs inside "information" field. And what to do if information comes as "" empty string sometimes (e.g. when "loginExist" is "") instead of {} data sets?

What is the *"dummycanunderstand"* way of doing this? Thank you.

**Json string:**

```
{   "response":"1",
    "loginExist":"1",
    "information":{  
        "code":"7452",
        "prefix":"thatschool",
        "student":{  
            "studentID":"3",
            "username":"username.username",
            "password":"passwordtext",
            "firstname":"Alan",
            "lastname":"Smith",
            "className":"5-A",
            "classID":"1"
        },
        "appointments":{  
            "past":"0",
            "today":"0",
            "future":"0"
        },
        "teachers":[  
            {  
                "teacherID":"3",
                "firstname":"David",
                "lastname":"Copperfield",
                "title":"Music",
                "picture":"93234234.jpg"
            },
            {  
                "teacherID":"5",
                "firstname":"John",
                "lastname":"Black",
                "title":"science",
                "picture":"99988.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MainResponse data gson.fromJson(responseAsJSON.toString(), MainResponse.class);

//I am getting the "response" string value and it works.
String responseText = data.response;
```

**MainResponse.java**

```
public class MainResponse{

    @SerializedName("response")
    String response;

    @SerializedName("information")
    //What to do when it comes to the nested arrays ???

    @SerializedName("loginExist")
    String loginExist;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to visit [here](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/). This website will create POJOs for your json string. [Create Json Pojo Online](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

0. Paste your Json string

1. Source Type : JSON

2.Annotation style : Gson

3. Preview / Download Jar (extract java files into your project).

Now you are ready to test.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that tool. It was very helpful. Now I have the classes for every object. But the app crashes when the json comes as below. When login info is wrong, information should be sent "". What should I do to make it work?

    {"response":"1","loginExist":"0","information":""}

Comment: at which line it is crashing?. As per your above json response don't read values from __information__ object as you don't have values to read. If you try to read values from information it will throw NullPointerException.

Comment: `MainResponse data = gson.fromJson(responseAsJSON.toString(), MainResponse.class);`

this line crashes because information is assigned to be an Information object. But this time it comes as a string "".

    `@Expose
    private Information information;`